# How to set z-index in css background

Tags: html, css

I have two backgrounds (calling from css), but first background is on full screen width and second is under it (is hidden). So I would like to set z-index, if it is possible. Do you know how to solve this problem? Thank you.

code

```
background-image:url("/images/background.png"), url("/images/fp_images/bg_image.png")
```

Comment: We need to see more code in order to answer your question. Please provide, at minimum, enough CSS and HTML to recreate your scenario.

Comment: give `z-index:-1` to background and `z-index:1` to the element above it

Comment: Look at this article, is about order like z-index: https://css-tricks.com/stacking-order-of-multiple-backgrounds

Comment: You can't set a z-index on background images. They're stacked in the order you list them, with the first at the top and the last on the bottom.

Comment: it is like in w3school (try it) ... 
body {
    background-image: url("paper.gif"),url('smiley.gif');
    background-repeat: repeat,norepeat;
} so I can not see smiley image

Comment: this question doesn't make sense, z-index is applied to the **item**, as is background-image. You can't apply css rules to other css rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do what you want to do as you want to do it. css rules (`z-index` and `background-image`) are applied to the **item**. You can't say x rule applies to y rule, that's not how CSS works.

the only solution you have is to have two items with different `background-image` and then apply the `z-index` to these.

### HTML

```
<div id="one"></div>
<div id="two"></div>
```

### CSS

```
/*on top*/
#one{
background-image:url("/images/background.png");
z-index:10;
}

/*underneath*/
#two{
url("/images/fp_images/bg_image.png");
z-index:5;
}
```

You'll have to make the items sit underneath each other too, likely using float's but this will depend on your overall design.

Comment: Your solution is fine and it is true that you cannot apply declarations to declarations in CSS; but your answer is not entirely correct, in that this is not the only way to do this. @patrick is correct, especially given the OP's question.

Answer (score 4):

As per the spec, the first image in the comma delimited list is on top.

The first image in the list is the layer closest to the user, the next one is painted behind the first, and so on. The background color, if present, is painted below all of the other layers.